# Native app is not authorizing other tenant users

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I have developed a custom mobile app on IOS, registered as native app on one tenant. The o365 mailbox users on this tenant able to configure mailbox on this app.

We added another user from different tenant as guest user, later changed his account type to member, given access to app. But user is not able to configure the mailbox  on the IOS app.

Error: The resource requires authorization or authorization was refused.[image]

Comment: Does the user have a mailbox on the same tenant?

Comment: yes he got the mailbox on same tenant.

Comment: Are they able to open their mailbox using OWA? https://outlook.office.com

Comment: yes he can access mailbox in owa

Comment: Can you please add the code you're using and the actual error content to your question? Screenshots are illegible.

Comment: Can you explain what “later changed his account to member” means? The mailbox of a guest user lives in an other tenant, you application cannot access a mailbox in an other tenant, if he is signed in to yours. He would need to sign in into his own tenant, your application would need to be multi tenanted if you want to access the mailbox of the guest.